# Get the average value of a table by day column in mysql

Tags: mysql, average

I try to get the average value of a table by day column, for example

```
table1
id  |  day  |  value |
F01 |  01   |   3    |
F02 |  02   |   2    |
F03 |  03   |   1    |
F04 |  04   |   2    |
F05 |  05   |   2    |
.   |  .    |   .    |
.   |  .    |   .    |
F30 |  30   |   4    |
F31 |  31   |   2    |
```

From the table above I want to get the average value of 5 days from the `value` column so in the above example I will get the value `2`. 
thanks before

Comment: Good, then go ahead and have a try. Post what you've tried. Hint: You'll need `avg()` , `group by` and google for `modulo`.

Comment: What !?!?!?!      !?!?!

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Sorry if there is something wrong in my question. I am still a beginner in programming language. And sorry also for my english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`AVG()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg):

```
SELECT `day` AS `Day`,
       AVG(`value`) AS `Average`
FROM `table`
WHERE `day` <= 5
GROUP BY `day`
ORDER BY `day` ASC;
```